# Canvas trouble on document.write

Tags: firefox, canvas, document.write

I have trouble in this code (I am working from my local PC).

Thks for your help.

My code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Test</title>
        <script src="../jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var _canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            _canvas.width="100";
            _canvas.height="100"; 
            var _context = _canvas.getContext("2d");
            var _img = new Image();
            _img.src = "image/myImgTest.png";
            var _url;

            _img.onload = function() {
            DrawScreen(); // just some process: drawing image
            _url = _canvas.toDataURL(); 
            alert("test"); **// this alert is printed on FF not on Chrome ???**
            // window.location = url; **// With this command on FF, I show my Image**
            document.write("<img src='"+url+"' >"); **// on FF, I show my image but when I would like to see the source code on my current page, there is nothing just blank ?? And on Chrome, I never show my image.** 

            **// In fact, I am expected to generate something like this: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo.....">  at this place **

            };
            function DrawScreen() {
                // my process
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**// In fact, I am expected to generate something like this:   at this place **

Comment: Even though I would strongly advise against using `document.write` nowadays ... You didn't show `DrawScreen()` where you supposedly copied the `_img` to the `_canvas`

Comment: My function is like that : function drawScreen(){

 _context.drawImage(_img,20,20,100,100,0,0,100,100);
};

Comment: My function is like that : function drawScreen(){ _context.drawImage(_img,20,20,100,100,0,0,100,100); }; some idea?

Answer (score 0):

As you are "working on your local PC" ... do you have a webserver on your local PC or do you just open the HTML file directly from your hard drive?

You might want to move the assignment of `.src` to after the `.onload` event handler, because otherwise it might be possible that `.onload` never gets triggered.

```
var _img = new Image();
var _url;

_img.onload = function() {
   ...
};
_img.src = "image/myImgTest.png";
```

Comment: Hi,I am working from hard disk without web server for my tests so just a html page.I will try with a web server...it would be bizare if it will work. Moreover, I tried to move _img.src after onload event: it is the same result on FF and I don't have anything on chrome. Thanks if you have some idea.